# Configuring hudson - confusion

Tags: hudson

I just installed hudson on Ubuntu, and I'm a bit confused by the general configuration options.

So, under `Manage Hudson -> Configure System`

You have the option to set JDK and Maven location. But what exactly do I do?
I've already defined these variables in the bash.bashrc file and added them to the PATH variable.

Do I add them here again, or is my previous definition enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your previous definition might be enough. However, you can define more than one java or maven version in Hudson. Works like a charm. If the number of your projects increase the chances that you need different Java version (e.g java 5 vs. 6 or openjdk vs sun), or different maven installations or different ant installations will increase.